# Counting clicks in Java

Tags: java, swing, oop, syntax

```
    introduceButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            int agex = Integer.parseInt(datafield.getText());

            String box[] = {"paws quantity", "tail(cm)","paws qy"};
            ArrayList<Integer> objdata =  new ArrayList<Integer>();

            for(int z = 0; z < 3;){
                introduceButton
                txtvar.setText(box[z]);
                if (introduceButton.getModel().isEnabled() == true){
                    z++;

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Hey guys, I try to count step by step how many times the button was pressed, to later navigate in an array.
The problem is that the variable z is not incrementing itself only by 1 after the button was clicked once but it reaches its max instantly after the first click. How can I fix it?
As well I tried to make a class with method counter but it the value remains 0:

```
class click{
    int _incr;
    public click(int incr){
        _incr = incr;
    }
    public int count(){
        _incr++;
        return _incr;
    }
}
```

...

```
introduceButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

        int agex = Integer.parseInt(datafield.getText());

        String box[] = {"paws quantity", "tail(cm)","paws qy"};
        ArrayList<Integer> objdata =  new ArrayList<Integer>();
        click clck = new click(0);
        txtvar.setText(Integer.toString(clck._incr));
            /*for(int z = 0; z < 3;){
                txtvar.setText(box[z]);
                if(introduceButton.getModel().isEnabled() == true){
                    z++;

                }
            }*/


        objdata.add(agex);

        dog abstractdog = new dog(agex, agex, agex);

    }
});
```

Comment: Post a [mre] as an [edit] to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I made a example code.
Please have a look at it:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class CountClick {

    static int clicks = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame f = new Frame("Button Example");

        Button btn = new Button("Click me");
        btn.setBounds(50, 100, 80, 30);
        f.add(btn);
        // set size, layout and visibility of frame
        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);

        // add listener
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // increase click int
                clicks++;
                // print clicks
                System.out.println(clicks);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Note that the code in "addActionListener" is triggered each time you press the button. Therefore, unnecessary operations in it should be avoided. Initialisations should also be used with care in the "addActionListener" method.

Edit:
If you want to have a separate click class you can have a look at following code example:

```
class Click {

    private int click = 0;

    public void increaseClick() {
        click++;
    }

    public int getClick() {
        return click;
    }

}

public class CountClicks {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame f = new Frame("Button Example");

        Button btn = new Button("Click me");
        btn.setBounds(50, 100, 80, 30);
        f.add(btn);
        // set size, layout and visibility of frame
        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);

        Click click = new Click();

        // add listener
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // increase click int
                click.increaseClick();
                // print clicks
                System.out.println(click.getClick());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: The code you suggested is nice, and works if I insert it in a new file and run in console. The problem is if I addapt it in my code it doesnt work. I ve moved instantiating the object before butons ActionListener, and have modified the click class, then oviously the button code but didn`t helped.

Comment: class click{
    int _incr;
    public click(int incr){
        _incr = incr;
    }
    public int count(){
        return _incr;
    }
}

Comment: click clck = new click(0);
        introduceButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                int agex = Integer.parseInt(datafield.getText());
                String box[] = {"paws quantity", "tail(cm)","paws qy"};
                ArrayList<Integer> objdata =  new ArrayList<Integer>();
                int incr = clck.count();
                incr++;
                txtvar.setText(Integer.toString(incr));
            }

Comment: Here is the code in readeble format https://paste. ofcode.org/Na4gbmSmEKdgqxc5NBgGKJ

Comment: Some advices:
1. initialise your buttons, labels, panels ... (Example: private Button btn1 = new Button();)
2. please have a CLOSE look at my code example!
3. clean up your code (helps you to keep it clear)